# How can Node.js enable different users do things in a sequence?

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am considering using Node.js to build a collaboration tool.  I want to realize that one user does something, enabling another user to do something.

So there is a sequence. If there are three users, the sequence would be 1,2,3,1,2,3...You can imagine a chess game with unlimited players.

So how can Node.js enable different users to do things in a sequence?

I really want some reference or code sample.

Many thanks.

Comment: You mean to give each user a turn?

Comment: Some of simple the introducing node.js examples are stateless. They are just very simple web server, which take the request, give a response and then forget the user's request. You, on the other side, need to save the actions. This can be done with variables (current server session only), files or databases (persistent storage). All of these facilities are supported by node.js.

Comment: @Zeta, could you give me some guidance that is more concrete..like what material i should read?

Comment: @alditis, yeah that's what i mean

Comment: @KarenPeng: Unfortunately I'm not a node.js programmer. I know some methods, but I don't know any frameworks at all and tried to give a more general hint. Have a look at some of the frameworks, like express. In a MVC environment you would add the current state to the model and enable a user (in his view) by controller actions.